# How to hash previously saved password in mysql using Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates, phpmyadmin

I'm building a Django app and working with existing database with it's own data.

I built login function and creating user accounts from admin side.

My question is how can I hash previously saved passwords in the database instead of re-creating accounts. Note: saved passwords are plain text not hashed. I need to take that passwords and apply make_password function to hash them but I don't know from where to start I'm new to Django

My views.py:
creating accounts:

```
@admin_login_required
def add_emp(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_name = request.POST['user_name']
        user_email = request.POST['user_email']
        user_otj = request.POST['user_otj']
        user_password = pwo.generate()
        user_password1 = make_password(user_password)
        empObj = User.objects.create(user_name=user_name, user_email=user_email, user_password=user_password1, user_otj=user_otj)
        if empObj:
            subject = 'Advanced Analytics Portal - Login Info'
            message = f'Name : {user_name}, \n Email : {user_email}, \n Password : {user_password} \n FROM - AA Portal'
            email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            send_mail(subject, message, email_from, [user_email])
            messages.success(request, "Employee was added successfully!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/create-emp')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Some error was occurred!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/create-emp')
    return render(request, 'AddEmp.html')
```

login view:

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_email = request.POST['user_email']
        user_password = request.POST['user_password']
        user_details = User.objects.filter(user_email=user_email).first()

        if user_details and check_password(user_password, user_details.user_password):
            request.session['logged_in'] = True
            request.session['user_email'] = user_details.user_email
            request.session['u_id'] = user_details.user_email
            request.session['user_name'] = user_details.user_name
            request.session['u_type'] = "emp"
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_index')
        else:
            return render(request, 'EmpLogin.html', {'msg': "0"})
    else:
        return render(request, 'EmpLogin.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer:

Get familiar with the django shell via the command `python manage.py shell`. There you can import your User model and change values and stuff.
Import also the User model from django and utilize [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) method: `.set_password()`

```py
from django.contrib.auth import User
from .models import MyUser
my_user = MyUser.objects.all().first() # grab just one user for demonstration purposes
print(User.set_password(my_user.plain_pw_field)) # prints hashed pw to console
```

#### Roadmap:

I understood your question like this. "I previously stored passwords in plain text. I recognized that is not state of the art. How to change it to the proper python-django way?"

Follow me here: 
First you want to inherit your user model from `AbstractUser`. Because then you get all these amazing functionalities listed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User). You then delete your "plain-password-field", because in future you want to use the password field of the `AbstractUser` which gets only stored hashed.

When you then do your migration it will ask "Hey, what to do with old Users, that now don't have a password". You want to go with set them manually and do the short answer above.

For sure you want to to this in a for loop iterating once over all your MyUser objects.

Read a lot about djangos `User` as it will help you a lot.

Let me know how it goes.